# Unsure why this JQuery code won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

This works inside my script section in a Jade file:

```
$('#viewUsersTbl').dataTable({
                        "sScrollY": "200px",
                        "bPaginate": false
                    });
```

This also works inside the same script section:

```
$.get('/showUsers', function(){

});
```

When I do this, why would the code inside the .get callback not work?

```
$.get('/showUsers', function(){
                     $('#viewUsersTbl').dataTable({
                        "sScrollY": "200px",
                        "bPaginate": false
                    })
                });
```

Comment: Because the callback isn't being ran. Most likely the error callback is happening instead. you likely won't see an error in the console as ajax errors typically happen silently unless caught using the error callback.

Comment: It should. Check your console, any errors?

Comment: `$.get(...).fail(errorCallback)` it has three parameters, the 2nd and third are the ones we need.

Comment: Yeah I'd try to just alert() out some text in the callback to make sure it's being called

Answer (score 1):

you might setup some error handling callback methods. I'm not a fan from jquery get and prefer $.ajax. The best way to use jqueries callback methods is by chaining them.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/file',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
    data: {param1: 'value1'},
})
.done(function() {
    console.log("success");
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
});
```

Comment: Tried that, I'm not seeing anything in the console.

Comment: if you don't see anything in the console then your ajax call is not fired. the snippet above will work 100% sure. Are you sure the ajax function is called?

Comment: I changed it back to jquery .get and applied the .fail() on it, an alert popped so it's failing. How can you see the actual error?